# Sometimes In PHP code I encounter phrase wrapped into _() like this _('some phrase')

Tags: php

Sometimes In PHP code I encounter phrase  wrapped into `_()` like this  `_('some phrase')`
what does `_()` mean ?

thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/_

Comment: This function is used for internationalization (multi-language support).

Comment: Use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=_%28%29++php) for search-terms like this. It doesn't ignore special characters.

Comment: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html

Answer (score 4):

That is a short-hand for `gettext()` function in PHP.

`_('some phrase')` -> `gettext('some phrase')`

[PHP Gettext docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)